# indexPath.row incorrect calculation on iPhone 6 simulator but not 4s/5/5s/6plus

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsindexpath

indexPath.row is being incorrectly calculated on iPhone 6 but not on any other simulator as seen below. The iOS deployment target is set to 8.0. This calculation happens when you click on the 2nd tab in a segmented control from (and only from) the 4th tab.

This is where the app crashes:

```
func createCompletedCell(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CompletedCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(profileCompletionId) as! CompletedCell
    println("indexPath.row: \(indexPath.row)")
    println("indexPath.row-2: \(indexPath.row-2)")
    var completion = switchState == 1 ? completionArr[indexPath.row-2] : favArr[indexPath.row-2] //crashes on this line

    cell.setCompletedCell(completion)
    return cell
}
```

Which was called from:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ProfileDetails", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileDetails
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None //No background color if cell is clicked
        return cell
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SegControl", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProfileSegControl
        cell.segControl.selectedSegmentIndex = switchState
        cell.segControl.addTarget(self, action: Selector("changeState:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        return cell
    }
    else {
        if(switchState == 0 || switchState == 2){
            return createBountyCell(indexPath)
        }
        else {
            return createCompletedCell(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

When I print the indexPath.row variable on an iPhone 6 simulator when I click on the 4th segmented control tab and then the 2nd, I get the output:

```
(4th tab calcs)    
indexPath.row: 2
indexPath.row-2: 0
indexPath.row: 3
indexPath.row-2: 1
(2nd tab calcs)
indexPath.row: 3
indexPath.row-2: 1
```

When I do the same but with iPhone 4s/5/5s/6plus

```
(4th tab calcs)    
indexPath.row: 2
indexPath.row-2: 0
indexPath.row: 3
indexPath.row-2: 1
(2nd tab calcs)
indexPath.row: 2
indexPath.row-2: 0
```

The problem is, when I click on the 2nd tab, indexPath.row should be set to 2 but is instead set to 3.

Comment: Have you taken a look at your storyboard?

Comment: Yes but nothing looked unusual. What exactly should I look at? @ILikeTau

Comment: The table view. Alternatively, can you try to sync up your changes with git and try again? (Remember to Reset Content and Settings in the simulator so everything is gone).

Comment: @ILikeTau had a look, everything appears fine. We did notice however we were both using different versions, which was the problem. We are still not sure why this occurs however.

Comment: Are they running the same version of iOS?

Comment: Probably some change in some Storyboard that you couldn't see

Comment: @ILikeTau the iOS deployment target in our projects is set to 8.0, so all simulators should be running 8.0

Comment: Show the actual code that generates that output.

Comment: Why doesn't it crash when `indexPath.row` is less than 2?

Comment: Not helpful. What calls `createCompletedCell`? You need to trace this all the way back to where the index path is obtained.

Comment: @ILikeTau I don't understand, why would it? It crashes because it is pointing to an index that doesn't exist - there is only 1 item in the array and  so indexPath should point to 0, not 1.

Comment: Yes, but aren't you doing `completionArr[indexPath.row-2]`, which would have an index of -1?

Comment: @ILikeTau no because the first two cells are statically set, hence the -2.

Comment: Okay, so there's no problem. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, the index path is not "calculated". It just is. It's the index path of the cell that the table happens to need at that moment. You should make no assumptions about it: you should just provide the cell that goes into whatever row it is.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is faulty. Consider an outline of your code. First you say this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 { // ...
    }
    else if indexPath.row == 1 { // ...
    }
    else {
        if(switchState == 0 || switchState == 2){ // ...
        }
        else {
            return createCompletedCell(indexPath)
        }
    }
}
```

Okay. So what index path is this when you call `createCompletedCell`? You don't know! You forgot to test that. Instead, you test something completely different - something about a `switchState`, which I have no basis for making any assumptions about. So `indexPath` row at this point can be *any number except 0 or 1* (because if it were one of those, we would have returned by now).

So you should not be surprised if it is 2, because your logic permits of that possibility. Your mistake is assuming later on that it *can't* be 2, since obviously it can be.

Comment: Our assumption was that cellForRowAtIndexPath was linear in progression ie starts at 0 and ends at X cells.  I presume that this is incorrect then from what you are saying?

Comment: Actually scrap that question, here's an example as to why it shouldn't crash: We have 5 items in our array.  We let the tableview know in NumberOfRowsInSection that we have 5 cells to create + 2 more for our static cells so 7 cells total.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath we check if the row is 0 or 1 for our static cells, else we want to retrieve an object from our array at indexPath.row-2 (minus 2 static cells).  This gives us results such as when indexPath.row is 5, we are retrieving object from array[3].  

In no case would indexPath.row > 6 (array[4]) as we specified a max of 7 cells earlier.